# Edit and Delete Button UITableView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I can put a UITableView into edit mode and show the delete button. How would I add a blue "Edit" button beside the delete button?

Just like swiping left in the mail in ios6, except the mail app shows "More", I want a "Edit" button.

Comment: `UITableViewCell` does not support such a feature. You need to roll your own. See https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a feature that comes standard with Apple's `UITableViewCell` - you're going to need to make your own subclass of `UITableViewCell` with your own swipe recognizer.

[This GitHub project](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) is a great start - using it, you should be able to use this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    SWTableViewCell *cell = (SWTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];

        [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
                    [UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.78f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0]
                    title:@"More"];
        [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
                    [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188 alpha:1.0f] 
                        title:@"Delete"];

        cell = [[SWTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                    reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier 
                    containingTableView:_tableView // For row height and selection
                    leftUtilityButtons:nil 
                    rightUtilityButtons:rightUtilityButtons];
        cell.delegate = self;
    }
...

return cell;
```

You then implement the delegate method for the cell:

```
- (void)swippableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"More button was pressed");
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            // Delete button was pressed
            NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

            [_testArray removeObjectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath] 
                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```